# Protractor: How to return element by executing js script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have the goal to return drop-down list of elements. I tried to do this with protractor's methods, but I hadn't found easy ways for searching isolate-span elements.
On that reason I want to use javasript code:

```
var my_js_element = browser.executeScript(jQuery("td.ng-binding>div.b-combobox.ps-list-drop-single-autocomplete.ng-isolate-scope.ng-pristine.ng-required.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required").isolateScope().psListDrop.toggleVisible(true).element);
```

But it isn't working. And I'm not sure that I can return elements with this method. Is it true? Or maybe somebody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs of `browser.executeScript`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript):

> If the script has a return value (i.e. if the script contains a return statement), then the following steps will be taken for resolving this functions return value: - For a HTML element, the value will resolve to a webdriver.WebElement.

From your `executeScript` call you should return an HTML element, also it should be a "native" DOM element, so it could be converted to [`webdriver.WebElement`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement). Then this element is resolved via promises and is available as an argument in a callback for `.then()`:

```
browser.executeScript(function () {

    var element = jQuery('.world').get(0); // get "native" DOM node

    return element; // explicit return

}).then(function (webElement) {

    expect(webElement.getText()).toContain('Hello');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

So Protractor is built ontop of the `WebDriver` specification.

According to the specification, it is possible to return values from executed scripts. It just might be JSON which would require you to convert it back. You can read more [here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#executing-script).

Try logging the value it returns. You might also explore using an XPATH selector to find your element.

Something like:

`//td[class="ng-binding"]/div[class="b-combobox" and class="ps-list-drop ...]`

Comment: Wow! I think that I will use JSON in the future. So, thank you for that useful source.