# ionic 4 e2e with protractor - how to dismiss a Toast

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, protractor, ionic4, e2e-testing

I want to be able to reliably dismiss a ionic 4 toast from within a protractor test.

I've tried

```
element(by.tagName('ion-toast')).then((res)=> res.dimiss)
```

But according to [Protractor: How to return element by executing js script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453313/protractor-how-to-return-element-by-executing-js-script) 
the promise returns a WebDriverElement and not the HTMLIonToastElement.

I've also tried

```
element(by.deepCss('toast-button-confirm')).click();
```

since the dimiss button itself is nested inside the ShadowRoot but that doesn't work somehow.

Comment: This may be the reason why `deepCss` isn't working. Appears that it's been deprecated. See the comments here https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6750456638341120

Answer (score 0):

Try the below after the pop up appears.

```
await browser.action().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESC).perform(); //If Esc close the popup then this helps.
```